# Not able to run a statement because of issue with the sql syntax

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-express

This solution is for an unbounded `Gridview` paging and having problem with the syntax of this query:

```
> @currTable varchar(20),
@startRowIndex int,
@maximumRows int, 
@totalRows int OUTPUT

AS

DECLARE @first_id int, @startRow int

IF @startRowIndex = 1 
SET @startRowIndex = 1
ELSE
SET @startRowIndex = ((@startRowIndex - 1) * @maximumRows)+1

SET ROWCOUNT @startRowIndex

DECLARE @sql varchar(250);   
SET @sql = 'SELECT ID, StringID_from_Master, GUID, short_Text, lang_String, date_Changed, prev_LangString, needsTranslation, displayRecord, brief_Descrip FROM ' + @currTable + ' ';
EXECUTE(@sql);

PRINT @first_id
SET ROWCOUNT @maximumRows
SELECT @sql = 'SELECT ' + CAST(@first_id as varchar(20)) + ' = ID FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@currTable) + ' ORDER BY ID ' ; 

EXEC (@sql);    

SET ROWCOUNT 0

-- Get the total rows 

SET @sql = 'SELECT ' +  + CAST(@totalRowsas varchar(20))  + ' = COUNT(ID) FROM ' + @currTable + ' ';  
EXECUTE(@sql);

RETURN
```

<

The errors is:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value ''SELECT ' to data type int.

Tried also

```
 nvarchar and varchar. = + CAST(@first_id as varchar(10)) +
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're trying to implement paging, this is wrong in so many ways. First, you're using SET ROWCOUNT to limit to @startRowIndex, but then you're selecting ALL n rows (with no ORDER BY), then getting the first ID, then counting the total rows by selecting from the table? Might I suggest a better approach?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.PageSmarter
    @Table     NVARCHAR(128), -- table names should not be varchar(20)
    @FirstRow  INT,
    @PageSize  INT,  
    @TotalRows INT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON; -- always, in every stored procedure

    DECLARE 
        @first_id INT, 
        @startRow INT,
        @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

    SET @sql = N'WITH x AS 
    (
        SELECT
            ID, 
            rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) 
        FROM 
            ' + @Table + '
    )
    SELECT rn, ID 
        INTO #x FROM x 
        WHERE rn BETWEEN ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), @FirstRow) 
            + 'AND (' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), @FirstRow) 
            + ' +   ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), @PageSize) + ' - 1);

    SELECT first_id = MIN(ID) FROM #x;

    SELECT
        ID, StringID_from_Master, GUID, short_Text, lang_String, date_Changed,
        prev_LangString, needsTranslation, displayRecord, brief_Descrip
        FROM ' + @Table + ' AS src
        WHERE EXISTS
        (
            SELECT 1 FROM #x
            WHERE ID = src.ID
        );';

    EXEC sp_executeSQL @sql;

    SELECT @totalRows = SUM(row_count)
        FROM sys.dm_db_partition_stats
        WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID(@Table);
END
GO

DECLARE @tr INT;
EXEC dbo.PageSmarter 'dbo.tablename', 10, 2, @tr OUTPUT;
SELECT @tr;
```

I haven't tested all edge cases with this specific implementation. I will confess, there are much better ways to do this, but they usually aren't complicated with the additional requirement of dynamic table names. This suggests that there is something inherently wrong with your design if you can run the exact same queries against any number of tables and get similar results.

In any case, you can review some of the (quite lengthy) discussion about various approaches to paging over at SQL Server Central:

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/66030/

There are 62 comments following up on the article:

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic672980-329-1.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing your @first_id field is an int.  If so, then you need to CAST/Convert your @first_id value to a string/varchar.

```
CAST(@first_id as varchar(10))
```

or

```
Convert(varchar(10), @first_id)
```

[MSDN documentation on CAST/Convert for SQL server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

EDIT: After looking at your query again, I notice that you are setting your @first_id = ID, This is incorrect syntax, the correct syntax would be below.

```
SELECT @sql = 'SELECT ID AS ' + CAST(@first_id as varchar(10)) + ' FROM ' +
                    QUOTENAME(@currTable) + ' ORDER BY ID ' ; 

EXEC (@sql);
```

Comment: Please don't specify `VARCHAR` without length. See this blog post for more information on why: https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It appears you're trying to create an alias for your column `ID`. The string you're building won't result in a valid SQL statement **if it contains a number**. It would come out to something like this:

```
 SELECT 123 = ID FROM dbo.MyTable ORDER BY ID
```

Try this:

```
SELECT ID AS '123' FROM dbo.MyTable ORDER BY ID
```

To achieve that:

```
SELECT @sql = 'SELECT ID AS ''' + CAST(@first_id as varchar(10)) + 
              ''' FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@currTable) + 
              ' ORDER BY ID ' ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way

```
create table #e (a int) 
SET @sql = 'insert #e SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM ' + @currTable + ' ';  
exec(@sql)
select @totalRows = a from #e
drop table #e
```